# Toggle a Bootstrap Toggle element with JavaScript (and show animation)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Toggle element as follows:

```html
<input id="neutralInd" type="checkbox" name="neutralSite" onchange="setEventSite('neutral')" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No">
```

Upon clicking it, it will toggle between Yes and No, and it successfully executes a JavaScript function that does other stuff (code below).

Here's what I want to do:

Upon selecting a Radio Button elsewhere on the page, it will execute JavaScript that toggles the Bootstrap Toggle to No. Here is the code I have so far:

Defining the radio buttons:

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" id="homeTeam<?php echo $row; ?>" name="homeTeam" onchange="setEventSite('team')"></label>
</div>
```

JavaScript function code:

```js
function setEventSite(chosen) {
  var neutralInd = document.getElementById("neutralInd"); // Toggle
  var locationOverride = document.getElementById("locationOverride"); // Text field
  var homeTeam = document.getElementsByName("homeTeam"); // Radio buttons

  if (chosen == "neutral") { // Toggle was clicked (changed)
    if (neutralInd.checked) {
      locationOverride.readOnly = false;
      for(var i=0; i<homeTeam.length; i++) { homeTeam[i].checked = false; }
    }
    else {
      locationOverride.value = "";
      locationOverride.readOnly = true;
    }
  } else if (chosen == "team") // Radio button was selected
  {
    neutralInd.checked = false;
    neutralInd.value="off";
    locationOverride.value = "";
    locationOverride.readOnly = true;
  }
}
```

When I choose a Radio Button, it successfully sets the Text field to Readonly, but the Bootstrap Toggle does not appear to toggle (it remains set to Yes when it should switch to No). **However, when I click the Toggle again, it stays on Yes yet executes the JavaScript as if it were being set to Yes. So that makes me think the value of the Toggle *is* successfully being set to No when I select a Radio Button, but the Toggle isn't displaying/animating the toggle to No.** *So maybe I'm asking how to make the Toggle show the animation of toggling to No.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a good friend.

I needed to add the "off" class to the parent element of the Toggle when the radio button was selected. So I had to add 2 lines to the function, and it works as desired:

```js
var parentInd = $("#neutralInd").parent();
parentInd.addClass("off");
```

So here is the resulting function code:

```js
    function setEventSite(chosen) {
      var neutralInd = document.getElementById("neutralInd");
      var locationOverride = document.getElementById("locationOverride");
      var homeTeam = document.getElementsByName("homeTeam");
      var parentInd = $("#neutralInd").parent();

      if (chosen == "neutral") {
        if (neutralInd.checked) {
          locationOverride.readOnly = false;
          for(var i=0; i<homeTeam.length; i++) { homeTeam[i].checked = false; }
        }
        else {
          locationOverride.value = "";
          locationOverride.readOnly = true;
        }
      } else if (chosen == "team")
      {
        neutralInd.checked = false;
        neutralInd.value="off";
        parentInd.addClass("off");
        locationOverride.value = "";
        locationOverride.readOnly = true;
      }
    }
```